# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un visor de mapas en WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, map

Hace unas semanas recibí permisos para usar este [visor de mapas personalizado](https://github.com/tibiamaps/tibia-map) de un fansite del juego del cual yo también estoy creando mi propio sitio fan y me gustaría integrarlo a mi propia web, el único detalle es que no sé por donde comenzar.

Estos son los archivos del mapa [tibia-map](https://github.com/tibiamaps/tibia-map)

Y así es como tiene que verse: [tibiamaps.io](https://tibiamaps.io/map#32368,32198,7:0)

Por lo tanto quisiera poder agregarlo a mi fansite, pero no tengo idea de cómo ni por dónde comenzar. Si alguien por favor me puede dar aunque sea una orientación para sentarme a investigar por mi cuenta, le estaré muy agradecido, ya que tampoco se ni siquiera por dónde comenzar a buscar o qué buscar exactamente, he intentado todo lo posible ante mi escaso conocimiento acerca del tema y he dado con más dudas que respuestas.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero agregue el map.js a su footer y los estilos main.css y map.css en su header y genere un div con el ID map que sera donde se dibujara su mapa, de esta forma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prueba de mapa</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tibiamaps.io/_css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tibiamaps.io/_css/map.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <h1>Visor de mapas de Tibia en línea</h1>
    <div id="map">
      <noscript>El visor de mapas interactivo de Tibia requiere JavaScript para funcionar.</noscript>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://tibiamaps.io/_js/map.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Los archivos los puedes descargar del sitio usando las urls del archivo como referencia, el mapa esta dibujado con canvas y js, por lo que si quiere realizar cambios tendrá que saber como usar los elementos canvas y trabajar un poco con js.

Si se va a descargar los archivos recomiendo usar alguna herramienta de unminify para descomprimir los css y los js para que sea mas legible al momento de editar el código, por ejemplo https://unminify.com/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfecto! Ya me encargaré de modificar el tamaño y algunas pautas de estilo. La verdad es que tratando de investigar llegué a leaflet y creí que por ahí era el tema, al menos en cuanto a estos mapas específicamente se refiere, ya me estaba arrancando los pelos con tanta información en la red y tanta desinformación en mi cabeza. Una vez mas muchísimas gracias, tus respuestas siempre son certeras, de verdad que si.